# $A\in GL_n(\mathbb Z)$ is a product of elementary matrices $E_1, \ldots, E_k \in GL_n(\mathbb Z)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'd like to show that if a matrix $A\in \mathbb Z^{n\times n}$ is invertible (with $A^{-1}\in \mathbb Z^{n\times n}$) then $A$ can be written as a product of elementary matrices $E_1, \ldots, E_k \in GL_n(\mathbb Z)$.

The only thing I know about matrices from $GL_n(\mathbb Z)$ is that their determinant is $\pm 1$.

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just make elementary row or column operations until the matrix becomes $I$. This isn't that different from the case of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. The only thing to keep in mind is that entries in each individual row cannot have a common divisor greater than $1$, because that would also be a divisor of $\operatorname{det} A$, and therefore you can always achieve a state when the given row has form $(0, \ldots, 0, 1, 0, \ldots, 0)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wlog. $a_{1,1,}\ne 0$ (use permutation matrices). With row operations (i.e. by multiplication with elementary matrices) you can perform division with remainder and you can swap rows, i.e. get from
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&\cdots\\b&\cdots\\\vdots&\ddots\end{pmatrix} \qquad\text{to}\qquad\begin{pmatrix}b\bmod a&\cdots\\a&\cdots\\\vdots&\ddots\end{pmatrix}$$
This allows you to perform the Euclidean algorithm on two entries, which ultimately takes you to $\begin{pmatrix}\gcd(a,b)&\cdots\\0&\cdots\\\vdots&\ddots\end{pmatrix}.$
You can repeat the procdure with the first vs. third row etc. until all but the first entry of the first columns are zero. The first entry is the $\gcd$ of all original entries and necessarily $1$.
After that, you can continue with the other columns until you obtain an upper triangular matrix with $1$ on the diagonal. From there you quickly arrive at the identity matrix.